# fo-dicom memory footprint and speed questions

Tags: architecture, memory-footprint

I have never used fo-dicom so far so I have more questions to find out whether it could help us out or my only option is to start developing low level SDK code for long years. I would like to use a managed SDK and fo-dicom seems to be getting extensive.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to write huge instances or create a huge instance on the fly when sending with using only negligible amount of memory? I should create a Per-Frame Group sequence with hundred millions of items and pixel data with the same amount of (little) frames. So I mean streaming should be supported for us.
2. Is it possible to avoid loading huge sequences into memory when only specific frames are needed from the instances?
3. Is it possible to get one frame compressed or uncompressed by giving its ordinal number within the containing pixel data without loading other parts into memory?
4. I would need a mechanism to find out the final length of an undefined-length sequence during writing or sending. I would store it in a private attribute of another instance and I would like to use that length to skip reading the huge sequence when reaching out the frames for a viewer.
5. Is character set handling already usable? (We have Asian, Arabic and other clients too). Our output is UTF8 as a default.
6. If only worklists are considered is there a managed SDK which is easier to be used for worklist development?

I would even gladly contribute to the development of fo-dicom but it is a question whether its architecture is suitable to complement it with those features without huge refactorings.
Thanks in advance for any info/help.

Answer (score 0):

What I think makes fo-dicom special, is that is completely portable managed. This means there is no managed SDK, but the whole fo-dicom is managed. Only for some jpeg compressions there is native code. So if you do not need jpeg compressions you can run fo-dicom in 32bit, 64bit, windows, andorid, ios, linux, unity, ... If you need native codecs you are limited to windows.

So ad 1. the limit of memory should only be the limit of your machines memory. But I do not have any benchmarks or experience with such big data. I am afraid, you just have to give it a try yourself.

ad 2. currently when opening a dicomfile then only the "header" without the pixels are loaded and the pixels are loaded from file if accessed the first time. This is currently not frame-based, but would be a good idea and not too hard to implement.

ad 3. same answer as in 2. currently the whole pixels are loaded from file. but then when you access a frame then the subset of the memory is returned and all further manipulations are performed on this subset.

ad 4. there is no api for that at the moment. but thats the great thing with open source, you can change it yourself whatever you need :-) this part is all c#.

ad 5. should be. at least i know that there have been a issue on github by a user some time ago with a image containing wrong encoded string, that have been solved. so assume it should be implemented, but I personally have not tested it.

ad 6. with fo-dicom you can implement any kind of service or client. Take a quick look at https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom-samples. In folder "Desktop" there is a worklist scp sample. Well if you find it easy to implement is up to you, but I like it :-)